# Stack trace as a string

Tags: logging, go

Is there any method to get a stack trace as a string?

Looking at the debug package (https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/debug/) it can only be printed to standard output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`runtime.Stack()` puts a formatted stack trace into a supplied `[]byte`. You can then convert that to a string.

You can also use `debug.Stack()`, which allocates a large enough buffer to hold the entire stack trace, puts the trace in it using `runtime.Stack`, and returns the buffer (`[]byte`).

Comment: Thanks! I should've looked at the source for `PrintStack` ( https://golang.org/src/runtime/debug/stack.go ). The function `debug.Stack` relies on `runtime.Stack` but catpures the entire buffer. I think that should ideally be used. Can you edit your answer, and I'll mark it as such?